# My new Macbook Air suddenly started giving me Facebook messages and I don't have a Facebook account

Tags: macos, facebook

I suddenly started getting Facebook messages from people I know, but I have never had a Facebook account. The notification pops up in the right hand corner just like my email notifications but they are talking to other people, not me of course since I have never had a Facebook account. Both my kids do but they have never accessed it from my computer that I am aware of. How do I know this isn't a hacking or spyware problem?

Answer (score 2):

Someone has setup the a facebook account and this is why you are getting notifications.
Go have a look in `Systeme Preferences > Mail, Contact & Calendar`.
And look for a facebook account on the left panel.
[image]

Comment: ok, i found it, a friend of mine actually used my computer the other day and must have looked at her facebook account. how do i get rid of it?

Comment: selection it and then click on the "-" on the bottom left.

Comment: you are welcome @user228121 dont forget to validate the answer!